# Tool or IDE giving hints about unused functions / missing parameters for PHP

Tags: php, function, ide, atom-editor

My project is growing fast and we are not always very conscientious with cleaning things and versioning correctly.
I find it hard to track unused functions and missused ones (missing parameters).

Is there a tool / IDE which permits to track this cases ? Ideally an Atom plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

1. [Atom Lint](https://atom.io/packages/atom-lint) package and linter package for your particular language.
2. [Atom Beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify) to help you clean your code.
3. Look for package for static analysis tools for your language.

Answer (score 1):

[Jebrains PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) is by far the best IDE I've ever used. It informs you of the things you ask and much more. It also has some pretty effective refactoring-features; say you want to change a function name - you just place the cursor on the function/method, press `Shift+F6`, write the new name, and PHPStorm will search through your entire project to find the usages and rename them accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For just checking a single class file I use this simple snippet of code:

```
<pre>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/ojsis.php';

$arr = file($file);

$foundMethods = array();
foreach ($arr as $line) {
    if (ereg ('function ([_A-Za-z0-9]+)', $line, $regs)) {
        $foundMethods[] = $regs[1];
    }
}

$usedMethods = array();
foreach ($arr as $line) {
    if (ereg ('\$this\-\>([_A-Za-z0-9]+)\(', $line, $regs)) {
        $usedMethods[] = $regs[1];
    }
}

$unusedMethods = array_diff($foundMethods, $usedMethods);
$misssingMethods = array_diff($usedMethods, $foundMethods);

echo "defined and never called internally:\n";
print_r($unusedMethods);
echo "\ncalled internally and not defined:\n";
print_r($misssingMethods);


?>
</pre>
```